# Unable to omit comma for decimal operand

Tags: javascript, regex

Anyone can explain to me how this regex able to add a comma to these expression?

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    // 1000 -> 1,000
    // 1000.01 -> 1,000.01
    // 100+1000 -> 100+1,000
    // 0.0001 -> 0.0,001 (known bug)
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=([0-9]{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: Adding those with regex is probably going to be a pain, I suggest you use `Intl.NumberFormat` instead. Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: `.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, x => Number(x).toLocaleString('en'))` or `.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, x => Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(x))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd select the whole floating point number and then format the integer part and the decimal places seperately:

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(
      /(\d*)(\.\d+)?/g, 
      (m, a, b="") => a.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d\d\d)+$)/g, ",") + b.replace(/\d\d\d\B/g, "$&,")
    );
}

[
    "1000",
    "1000.01",
    "100+1000",
    "0.0001",
    "1500.00000001"
].forEach(v => console.log("%s -> %s", v, numberWithCommas(v)));
```

without lookbehinds, I don't know a better way to exclude sequences of digits after a dot.

Comment: for this, how to omit the comma? 0.0001 -> 0.000,1

Comment: this part is doing these: `b.replace(/\d\d\d\B/g, "$&,")`